# How to parse weird Python Request response?

Tags: python, json, xml, web-scraping, python-requests

I am doing a piece of work for a client and I need to get some data from their website.  Hitting their endpoint with a random post code the correct JSON results in success but the response is not what I'd expect.

It actually looks like it's valid JSON but contains escaped HTML in the HTML key as well as new line and returns before and after.

I can parse it as a dictionary using:

```
json_string = json.loads(r.text)
```

I can't access the HTML key within it though as Python says it's a string..

In fact I have no idea what to do.. any ideas how I can parse this in Python please so I can put the HTML into beautiful soup?

```
 {'d': '{\r\n  "result": "200",\r\n  "HTML": "<table style=\\"max-width:750px;\\"><tr id=\'resultsHeader2\'><th class=\'thMid\'>Select</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Address</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Street</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Area</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Postcode</td></tr><tr class=\'tResults\' id=\'uprnRow0\'><td id=\'uprnButton0\'><button type=\'button\' onclick=\\"changeText(\'uprnButton0\',\'Loading\');populAddr(\'105 BERKSHIRE DRIVE RAMLEAZE SWINDON SN1 5RP\');getobject(\'divAddress\').innerHTML = \'\';GetInfoAndRoundsFor(\'345634564356\',\'SWN\');\\" title=\'Get Calendar for this address\'>Show</button></td><td>105</td><td>BERKSHIRE DRIVE</td><td>RAMLEAZE<br/>SWINDON</td><td>SN1 5RP</td><tr class=\'tResults\' id=\'uprnRow1\'><td id=\'uprnButton1\'><button type=\'button\' onclick=\\"changeText(\'uprnButton1\',\'Loading\');populAddr(\'150 BERKSHIRE DRIVE RAMLEAZE SWINDON SN15 5RP\');getobject(\'divAddress\').innerHTML = \'\';GetInfoAndRoundsFor(\'3456346435634\',\'SWN\');\\" title=\'Get Calendar for this address\'>Show</button></td><td>150</td><td>BERKSHIRE DRIVE</td><td>RAMLEAZE<br/>SWINDON</td><td>SN15 5RP</td><tr><td class=\'tableFoot\' colspan=\'5\'></tr></table>",\r\n  "r1": "Swindon",\r\n  "r2": "",\r\n  "r3": ""\r\n}'}
```

I've not seen it before and it looks hideous... :-)

Updated with value of r.text:

```
{"d":"{\r\n  \"result\": \"200\",\r\n  \"HTML\": \"\u003ctable style=\\\"max-width:750px;\\\"\u003e\u003ctr id=\u0027resultsHeader2\u0027\u003e\u003cth class=\u0027thMid\u0027\u003eSelect\u003c/td\u003e\u003cth class=\u0027thMid\u0027\u003eAddress\u003c/td\u003e\u003cth class=\u0027thMid\u0027\u003eStreet\u003c/td\u003e\u003cth class=\u0027thMid\u0027\u003eArea\u003c/td\u003e\u003cth class=\u0027thMid\u0027\u003ePostcode\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr class=\u0027tResults\u0027 id=\u0027uprnRow0\u0027\u003e\u003ctd id=\u0027uprnButton0\u0027\u003e\u003cbutton type=\u0027button\u0027 onclick=\\\"changeText(\u0027uprnButton0\u0027,\u0027Loading\u0027);populAddr(\u00275 BERKSHIRE DRIVE RAMLEAZE SWINDON SN5 5RP\u0027);getobject(\u0027divAddress\u0027).innerHTML = \u0027\u0027;GetInfoAndRoundsFor(\u00345643564536\u0027,\u0027SWN\u0027);\\\" title=\u0027Get Calendar for this address\u0027\u003eShow\u003c/button\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e5\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eBERKSHIRE DRIVE\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eRAMLEAZE\u003cbr/\u003eSWINDON\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eSN5 5RP\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctr class=\u0027tResults\u0027 id=\u0027uprnRow1\u0027\u003e\u003ctd id=\u0027uprnButton1\u0027\u003e\u003cbutton type=\u0027button\u0027 onclick=\\\"changeText(\u0027uprnButton1\u0027,\u0027Loading\u0027);populAddr(\u002715 BERKSHIRE DRIVE RAMLEAZE SWINDON SN5 5RP\u0027);getobject(\u0027divAddress\u0027).innerHTML = \u0027\u0027;GetInfoAndRoundsFor(\u3456345634575\u0027,\u0027SWN\u0027);\\\" title=\u0027Get Calendar for this address\u0027\u003eShow\u003c/button\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e15\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eBERKSHIRE DRIVE\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eRAMLEAZE\u003cbr/\u003eSWINDON\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eSN5 5RP\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd class=\u0027tableFoot\u0027 colspan=\u00275\u0027\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\",\r\n  \"r1\": \"Swindon\",\r\n  \"r2\": \"\",\r\n  \"r3\": \"\"\r\n}"}
```

Comment: That looks like HTML in JSON in JSON.

Comment: Try using any encode format to convert it to proper string

Comment: Actually it's a valid JSON, but maybe you mishandle the response. Show your code that produce it.

Comment: can we see the actual value of  r.text

Comment: Yep just amended.. I'm hoping I've not missed something obvious..

Comment: It that is `r.text` then this service you are consuming either: 1) Has a bug 2) This is the expected behavior. If you have control over this service, I would make changes there, otherwise, check their documentation and raise a ticket if you think this is unexpected behavior. Finally, it looks like there is a JSON inside the `"d"` attribute, so I would try `json.loads` that after cleaning it up: `json.loads(json_string['d'].replace('\r\n', ''))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something weird going on with this service. Check my comment on the question. It seems like there is an additional JSON array inside the attribute `"d"` of the original JSON array:

```
json.loads(json.loads(r.text)['d'])
```

I get:

```
{
     u'HTML': u'<table style="max-width:750px;"><tr id=\'resultsHeader2\'><th class=\'thMid\'>Select</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Address</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Street</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Area</td><th class=\'thMid\'>Postcode</td></tr><tr class=\'tResults\' id=\'uprnRow0\'><td id=\'uprnButton0\'><button type=\'button\' onclick="changeText(\'uprnButton0\',\'Loading\');populAddr(\'105 BERKSHIRE DRIVE RAMLEAZE SWINDON SN1 5RP\');getobject(\'divAddress\').innerHTML = \'\';GetInfoAndRoundsFor(\'345634564356\',\'SWN\');" title=\'Get Calendar for this address\'>Show</button></td><td>105</td><td>BERKSHIRE DRIVE</td><td>RAMLEAZE<br/>SWINDON</td><td>SN1 5RP</td><tr class=\'tResults\' id=\'uprnRow1\'><td id=\'uprnButton1\'><button type=\'button\' onclick="changeText(\'uprnButton1\',\'Loading\');populAddr(\'150 BERKSHIRE DRIVE RAMLEAZE SWINDON SN15 5RP\');getobject(\'divAddress\').innerHTML = \'\';GetInfoAndRoundsFor(\'3456346435634\',\'SWN\');" title=\'Get Calendar for this address\'>Show</button></td><td>150</td><td>BERKSHIRE DRIVE</td><td>RAMLEAZE<br/>SWINDON</td><td>SN15 5RP</td><tr><td class=\'tableFoot\' colspan=\'5\'></tr></table>',
     u'r3': u'',
     u'result': u'200',
     u'r2': u'',
     u'r1': u'Swindon'
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this! This worked and I'm glad it wasn't just me who thought it was weird.. I will give them this feedback.